# Парсинг xml с большой вложенностью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xmlparser

есть xml типа

```
<Список>
 <Актуальный список>
  <Заключение>
   <Объект>
   <Объект>
   <Объект>
  </Заключение>
  <Заключение>
   <Объект>
  </Заключение>
 </Актуальный список>
</Список>
```

Блоков "Заключение" достаточно большое количество, а подблоков "Объект" в этих блоках не фиксировано.
На данный момент код парсит только первые подблоки и дальше не проваливается. Как реализовать проверку всех подблоков и возможную более глубокую вложенность? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # vim:fileencoding=utf-8
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import csv


    tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()

    # открываем файл для записи

    file_out = open('file_out.csv', 'w', newline='')

    # создаем шапку
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=';')
    columns = ["AdditionalReason","StartDate"]
    csvwriter.writerow(columns)
    count = 0
    for member in root.find('АктуальныйСписок').findall('Заключение'):
        mass =[]
        # AdditionalReason
        additional_reason = member.find('ВидЗаключения').find('Идентификатор').text
        mass.append('приостановление' if additional_reason == '1' else '')
        # StartDate
        start_date = member.find('ДатаЗаключения').text
        mass.append(start_date)
        csvwriter.writerow(mass)
        count += 1
    file_out.close()
```

Comment: Чтобы перебрать "Объекты" неизвестного количества используйте цикл, а чтобы перебрать теги неопределённой вложенности используйте рекурсию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте функцию `iter` для поиска на любом уровне вложенности нужного тега.

Модифицированный файл:

```xml
<Список>
 <АктуальныйСписок>
  <Заключение>
   <Объект/>
   <Объект/>
   <Объект/>
  </Заключение>
  <Заключение>
   <Объект/>
  </Заключение>
  <Другое>
   <Второе>
      <Заключение>
       <Объект/>
       <Объект/>
       <Объект/>
      </Заключение>
   </Второе>
  </Другое>
 </АктуальныйСписок>
</Список>
```

Код:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# Поиск тегов <Заключение> на любом уровне
for member in root.iter('Заключение'):
    print(member)

    # Перебор детей <Объект>
    for obj in member.findall('Объект'):
        print('   ', obj)

    print()
```

Консоль:

```
<Element 'Заключение' at 0x00000000029C83B8>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A0FF98>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A2F048>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A2F688>

<Element 'Заключение' at 0x0000000002A36778>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A367C8>

<Element 'Заключение' at 0x0000000002A368B8>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A36908>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A36958>
    <Element 'Объект' at 0x0000000002A369A8>
```

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, подправил

Comment: спасибо. Для работы кода необходимо переработать входной xml или его модификация добавлена для наглядности?

Comment: @AlexKady, для наглядности

Comment: спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: А вам критичен Python? Возьмите SmartXML и не парьтесь.
https://redata.dev/smartxml/